# How to extract FROM,TO,SUBJECT,BODY,ATTACHMENT fields from multipart/form-data coming through AWS API in string format (contain \n\r)

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, sendgrid, busboy

I have configured SendGrid Inbound Parse webhook to get email content on my AWS API endpoint.

So I am getting email content in multipart/form-data format but in string which contains \n\r.

```
AWS API event.body= --xYzZY\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="dkim"\r\n\r\n{@perficient.onmicrosoft.com : pass}\r\n--xYzZY\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="subject"\r\n\r\nFW: Test email
```

I want to extract fields like FROM, TO, Subject, Body, Attachment technology using NodeJS

After replacing \n\r with \n & process body with structured multipart form data getting following error

```
{ "errorType": "Error", "errorMessage": "Unexpected end of multipart data", "stack": [ "Error: Unexpected end of multipart data", " at /var/task/node_modules/dicer/lib/Dicer.js:61:28", " at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)" ] }
```

Answer (score 0):

Suggest using a node library like [formidable](https://github.com/node-formidable/node-formidable) to do all the hard work of parsing multipart/form-data for you.  This will likely avoid the problem in the first place.